# Google Analytics API Python Error 403 - Insufficient Permissions

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I've set my analytics api and credentials, downloaded the client_secrets.json and copied the client_email.

Then, I went to my Google Analytics account > property > view > admin > User Management and added that email as a new user with read permissions.
This went just fine, no error or whatsoever.

Now, when I try to make use of the api via python, i get this error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.". Details: "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.">
```

I'm going crazy with this. Don't know what's going on and how to fix it.

Code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'client_secrets.json'
VIEW_ID = 'view_id' #exampe '12341234'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
    analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
    return analytics


def get_report(analytics):
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
                    'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
                    'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}]
                }]
        }
    ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  Args:
    response: An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print(header + ': ', dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print('Date range:', str(i))
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print(metricHeader.get('name') + ':', value)


def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Can someone help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Done, @DalmTo Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same error message and it turned out that the issue was coming from the fact that I was calling the Google Analytics Reporting API v4 for a Google Analytics **GA4** property which is not supported according to Google documentation.

I tried calling the same API for a Google Analytics **GA3 (Universal Analytics)** property and it worked.

If you are using the latest Google Analytics (GA4) please call the Google Analytics Data API.

Link to the documentation:

[Google Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4)

[Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)

Comment: Indeed, this is what I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

Means that the user you are currently authenticating with does not have permissions to access the account you are trying to access.

You need to add the user via the Google analytics admin as you have done. Make sure you added it at the account level.

I would suggest that you double check that you added the correct user email address, and then check that you are using the correct view id.

[User doesn't have any google analytics accounts easy solution](https://youtu.be/s0fwl7tbS8U)

You miss typed something.

Comment: I've entered the correct email from the client_secrets.json under account level and still get the same result

Comment: Are you using a service account?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a service account and its status is active

Comment: And you created the on https://console.cloud.google.com/ and enabled the google analytics api.   I still think the issue is with either the VIEW id you are using or the service account email address that you added

Comment: Did you happen to solve this @pyseo? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @gwrathe did you try granting access?